# Empty DBM , Parser.pm line 185 in MEAD

Tags: full-text-search, text-mining, summarization

TO All,

My objective to summarize text document. When I using MEAD summarizer system I find two problem.

I am using Perlv5.14.2, mead 3.11, Download all relevant dependencies, using UBUNTU O.S.

Kindly tell me solution 4 my problme.

Empty DBM /home/scssjnu/Desktop/mead/etc/enidf at /home/scssjnu/Desktop/mead/bin/../lib//Essence/IDF.pm line 43.

no element found at line 1, column 0, byte 0 at /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2/XML/Parser.pm line 185

THANK YOU

Answer (score 0):

THIS LINE WORKED :
TYPE :

bin/write-idf.pl etc/enidf etc/enidf.txt ///  HERE IT IS {"http://lists.si.umich.edu/pipermail/mead.mbox/mead.mbox"}

again run : like

mead.pl -extract GA3

i am getting output now......

thnx TO MAINTAIN dATABASE